# Compile and Run C code in MonoDevelop on Ubuntu

Tags: c, monodevelop

I have C code and I want to compile and run this code in MonoDevelop on Ubuntu. 
I am new both to Ubuntu and MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Creating C and C++ projects in Monodevelop` http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Creating_C_and_CPP_Projects